# SilverStripe default content author permissions

Tags: php, silverstripe

The default value for **Manage site configuration** is **off**
*security > groups > content authors > permissions*

[image]

Although it's possible to simply check the box and activate this, I would rather have this on by default for every SS installation.

How can the default value for this be set to **on**?

Comment: btw any chance you could tag PHP on these questions as that is the language of choice for Silverstripe?

Comment: Absolutely, added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do as required, make an extension of `Group` and add a `requireDefaultRecords` function, this is called on every dev build.

This function is to look for that permission and if not existing create it...

```
class GroupExtension extends DataExtension {

    function requireDefaultRecords() {

        //get the content-authors group
        if ($group = Group::get()->filter('Code','content-authors')->first()) {

            //expected permission record content
            $arrPermissionData = array(
                'Arg'       => 0,
                'Type'      => 1,
                'Code'      => 'EDIT_SITECONFIG',
                'GroupID'   => $group->ID
            );

            //if the permission is not found, then create it
            if (!Permission::get()->filter($arrPermissionData)->first())
                Permission::create($arrPermissionData)->write();
        }
    }

}
```

As ever to register the extension add this to your config.yml...

```
Group:
  extensions:
    - GroupExtension
```

Comment: Cheers Barry, could you run over the code one more time? There seem to be some issues. I think 'content-authors' should be in brackets and `arrPermissionData` throws a SS error

Comment: missing quote there yes, sorry

Comment: on dev/build?flush it returns: `Use of undefined constant arrPermissionData - assumed 'arrPermissionData'`

Comment: after putting `arrPermissionData` in brackets it returns: `[Warning] Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Line 381 in ..../public_html/framework/model/DataList.php`

Comment: missing "$" is also now fixed

Comment: No more errors! I've added this class to a bare SS 3.4 installation and ran dev/build?flush. The checkbox is still unchecked, and content users still have no permission to view *Settings* aka SiteConfig

Comment: ok, so I've fixed one more missing "$" and actually tested it as well and it is working fine... can you try again... as I say yes there were some small syntax errors... but it's worked fine for me now

Comment: That last change did the job. Thanks again Barry